# How to call different intents from each listview item in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator

I have over 10 rows in my listview and I am fetching records from web URL using JSON but now i want to call particular intent for each row, like:-for first row , I want to call ([`this`](http://domainname.com/s/a)), for the second row,(http://domainname.com/s/b) and so on,
So please suggest what code i need to add in my ListActivity class and where to call....

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView mListView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);    

    // URL to the JSON data 
    String strUrl = "http://domainname.in/first.php/count/";

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data 
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

    // Starting the download process
    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

    // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_count);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by writing your own custom adapter. like below :

```
  class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    HashMap<String, String> map;
    ArrayList mList;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            int textViewResourceId, HashMap<String, String> map) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        this.map = map;
        mList = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // do your stuff with layouts.
        String item = (String)mList.get(position);
        // either you can set the url as tag to view so that the same url will be
        //retrieved when an item is clicked or declare the map as global variable.
        String url = map.get(item);
        convertView.setTag(url);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

/// in your activity

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    // you can get the url from the tag
    String url = view.getTag().toString();
    // or else declare the HashMap as global variable which will be accessible through out the class.
    String url = new ArrayList<String>(map.keySet()).get(position);
    // Now launch web with this url
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the `ListView` data with the URL specified for each item and the you can handle ListView's `onItemClick()` get the ListView item fetch URL from the basis of selected item and open  the link in WebView.